# Powershell: Format numbers in filenames using Rename-item?

Tags: powershell, formatting, rename-item-cmdlet

I am trying to rename files that are in sequence. The new file name will include a variable that distinguishes it. How to I format that variable so that it is always 2 digits?

```bsh
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "FileName$x.jpg'; $x++}
```

This is the line I bastardized from multiple sources to try and get it done, but whenever I try to format the variable, I keep running into errors.

I am new to powershell.

Comment: take a look at the `-f` string format operator. it allows you to tell PoSh to use a certain number of digits. this >>> `'{0:D2}' -f 1` <<< will give you this >>> `01` <<<

Comment: i've tried that and I dont know where to put the -f. I've tried

`Get-ChildItem *.jpg | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName 'FileName{:d2}.jpg' -f $x; $x++}`

But all it did was create an error in the Rename-Item function

Comment: i see that js2010 showed how to  use it ... glad to know that you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the rename-item saga continues.  Expressions as command arguments need '( )' around them.

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | 
  %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('FileName{0:d2}.jpg' -f $x++) -whatif }
```

With -f, '0' is the first item, then '1', etc.

```
'{0} - {1} - {2}' -f 1,2,3
```

You would need '$( )' for multiple statements:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | 
  %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName $('FileName{0:d2}.jpg' -f $x; $x++) }
```